# Which model Should I prefer for Partner Program ? and How Can I become Partner?

Tags: community, appexchange, partner-portal, force.com-embedded

I have developed a portal which I am showing as Tab in the salesforce. I want to publish my application and when user install in the his/her account, it will show that portal in the Tab. But, before publishing any application, I want to make sure which model should I prefer Partner Program ?
ISV or OEM ? I have sign up in ISV model with personal email Id. but, looks like I am not partner. Until, I pay something.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a few stages to becoming a partner so your account won't just be activated by signing up online.

That said, OEM is not likely to be a suitable candidate for your app since you just want to expose something else via the platform, OEM is for when you've built a product on the platform that doesn't use the standard features and that you want to sell to people who don't use Salesforce already.

Comment: Ok. @LaceySnr. but, In order to use my application in the salesforce account as Custom Tab, End user must have salesforce account. and they will install into salesforce account. so, Should I use ISV ? if yes, How should I pay or become partner after sign up into https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/partnerSignup 
What are the steps ?

Comment: I don't know all of the steps myself, but yes, you need to be ISV, and you will have to pay to have the app reviewed and made available on the AppExhange.

Comment: Ok. if I become ISV program partner. Do I need to pay $2700 for security review, if my application is free, and require to pay $150 every year for listing out app on appexchange ?

Comment: I don't need to pay $2700 for security review. and will have to pay $150 every year for listing of app on appexchange. got the answer from below link.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review_FAQ

Answer (score 0):

I need to use partner with ISV model as our application is going to be used by existing salesforce customer.